# Custom shape graph in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

Currently I am trying to make a histogram of a baseball strike zone for the pitches that looks like the one from Baseball Savant.
[image: Baseball Savant Graph]

I have already determined the pitches' position with numbers and those are already in the dataframe, but I don't know how to draw the graph like this in Python, preferably Plotly. Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example